# Wordpress Home page URL changing to /?i=1 - issue

Tags: wordpress, url

When I try to access my **Wordpress** website directly or from google, the Home page URL automatically adding `/?i=1` and sometimes `/?i=2` to the URL in the address bar.

I think it's a very simple to solve it, but I tried many things and didn't work.

So I wonder how can I solve this to be only the `URL without /?i=1 or /?i=2` ?

Comment: When you join your page second time do you see this extension again?

Comment: No, only the first time.

Comment: You should ask this question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ . For stack overflow as the question is formed now it's impossible to guess why this happens as there is no [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/?i=1 or /?i=2 protects your website from bots and is mostly applied by free hosting services and if you use any .htaccess code to remove it than all ? parameters will removed and redirect you to homepage

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your wordpress permalink from admin end. If you don't know how to do that check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LX1krDC7Rtc).  As this is not normal behavior of wordpress you can also check your .htaccess file.

Comment: I reset the permalink but didn't solve it and I think my .htaccess is fine here is it :


`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)i=[^&]+(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Add this in htaccess